# What does jQuery .remove() on null element?

Tags: jquery

I have `$('#something').find('#something').remove()` in my code.

I was just wondering what happens if `find()` returns null.  I tried it actually and it doesn't show any error and works fine. So, what happens if we call remove on a null element?

This is a basic question but couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Nothing happens. jQuery is very fault tolerant. The returned value will be an empty jQuery object.

Comment: It removes each of the zero elements in the jQuery collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it,
If find() didn't get resulted data then nothing will happen if you check in console.log it retun an object with length

**If you do `console.log($("ul").find("span"));` it will retun object with length**

```
w.fn.init(2) [span, span, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
0: span
1: span
length: 2
prevObject: w.fn.init [ul, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

**If you do `console.log($("ul").find("div"));`in this case descendant child div did not exist so it will retun object with length 0**

```
w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: w.fn.init [ul, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

You can check this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").find("li").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
</script>
</head>

<body class="ancestors">body (great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (grandparent)
    <ul>ul (direct parent)  
      <li>li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**You can get more idea about find**

https://api.jquery.com/find/

**I hope it will help you.**

Comment: And what happens when we call .remove() on that object with length 0. What is it going to do? Or how is it going to treat that?